# Call Existing Flow From A New Flow and Continue with New Flow Afterwards

Tags: spring-integration

I would like to reuse an existing flow chain without changing its expected payload and call it from a new flow.  However, I am not sure how to call the existing flow without losing the payload from the new flow.  And it all has to be in one transaction. I am using Spring Integration DSL Lambdas.  Here is what it looks like

```
            Validation Flow B
                     |
                   Route
                   /   \
         Error Flow    Existing Validation Flow A -- Existing Persist Flow A
                                                              |
                                  ----------------------------
                                  |
                           New Persist Flow B
```

After Persist Flow A is successful I would like to continue with the original payload from Validation Flow B into Persist Flow B.  Should I save this in the header?  I know how to set values in the header.  How do you set a payload in the header using DSL.  Or is there a way to store a claim check in the header and not the payload using DSL?

Answer (score 1):

There are several techniques and components to call one flow from another. And all concepts and principles come from original [Spring Integration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/).

One of them is `.gateway()`, when you send messages to the request channel and wait for reply from that sub-flow or another flow. But in this case the `reply` becomes a `payload` for the next endpoint in the main flow.

Another components is `.enrich()` where you do almost the same as with `.gateway()`, but will enrich the existing `payload` or `headers` basing on the reply. And I think for your use-case you can just omit both `headers` and `properties` enrichment there, if you would like continue with the same `payload`.

Anyway I'd say that your use-case looks like `.publishSubscribeChannel()` with two subscribers for the same `payload`. Where an existing flow should be as a first subscriber and a new flow as a second. Everything should be configured without any `Executor` (default) and therefore the second flow will be called only after the successful finish of the first one.

You can store `payload` in the `headers` like:

```
.enrichHeaders(h ->
        h.headerFunction("originalPayload", Message::getPayload))
```

Comment: Thanks adding the payload to the header as mentioned.

Comment: If that answers to you question, that would be great to see an *Accept* and earn good reputation here on SO.